# The *Design.cs file will reset automatically and delete the manually writed codes?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I need change the some Initialized control values, as below:

```
        this.lblName.Top = 10;
        this.lblFamily.Top = this.lblName.Top + this.lblName.Height + 15;
        ...
```

When I write these codes in `InitializeComponent()` method (*Which automatically created in [Windows Form Name]Designer.cs file which this file is a Windows Form `partial class` container*), sometimes this codes will deleted automatically and sometimes bring error warning in *.cs[Design] view and will delete above manually added codes, after ignoring that prompt.

> I want add new controls and assign it's initialized property values manually by write appropriated codes in *Designer.cs file

How can I assign initialized values of controls properties?

&

Why the *Designer.cs file will reset automatically or return error page in *.cs[Design] tab?

Comment: TL;DR; **never** ever modify a `*.designer.cs` file. That's why it's a *designer* file and that's why it includes a message stating NOT to change the file at the top.

Comment: You're modifying a generated file, and when it is re-generated, you're wondering why?  It's a *generated* file.  Don't modify it!

Comment: "This file was generated by a tool".

Don't be a tool :D

Comment: Am I not allowed to change the generated file? What is the best method of **declare and add and assign initialize** properties of windows form controls?

Comment: You have an answer below.  Perhaps you should review it.

Comment: [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) anyone?

Comment: @MischaBehrend
The problem is basically, that, when starting with something, one does not know all the concepts, ways of doing things. So formulating a question is hard and sometimes result in "I ask for that, but really i mean this". So in this case its useless to answer "How to stop Visual Studio overriding the designer file?" directly, but to explain: what concept (separation of concerns) lies behind this behaviour and why you should not change/add code in there.

Comment: why not set these properties in the designer using the object inspector ?

Comment: because this ```this.lblFamily.Top = this.lblName.Top + this.lblName.Height + 15;``` will not work in Object inspector since its a statement. Ok you could calculate it before...

Comment: oops I was to quick with my comment

Comment: was a good question though :)

Comment: @FrankM You got me wrong, I think... "How to stop VS overriding files" is the Y in this case. Why he want to edit the generated file is the X that really needs to be asked

Comment: @MischaBehrend yes, that can only the OP know excactly. I guess (now), he wants to design the form programmatically, to look even and good:```this.lblFamily.Top = this.lblName.Top + this.lblName.Height + 15;``` is a hint for that. so you got a point. so "how to use the designer to make forms look good" could also be the question behind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 Files for you Form:

**MyFormClass.cs**  here you can edit as you like, add Properties, change them, etc.

**MyFormClass.designer.cs** // auto generated, dont put stuff here

Put your custom code in the constructor after the InitializeComponent() call

```
public MyFormClass()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    // do it here
    this.lblName.Top = 10;
    this.lblFamily.Top = this.lblName.Top + this.lblName.Height + 15;
}
```

It is the 2nd half of the partial class definition, so you have acces to all the Properties.

File1:

```
namespace Test{
    public partial class MyFormClass{
    // add some code
    }
}
```

File2:

```
namespace Test{
public partial class MyFormClass{
    // add some code here
    }
}
```

Comment: Regards. How can I add a new specific partial class in the Windows Form folder, near the **MyFormDesigner.cs** and **MyForm.resx** files? If true, please guide me asking new question about.

Comment: its done automatically in Visual Studio, but you can create a class file and put your code there, just use the same namespace

Comment: I'm not permitted to add a new file in **MyForm.cs** folder, near the two above auto-generated files? (A partial class for **MyForm** class to solve above)

Comment: What do you mean you aren't permitted to add a file?  What?

Comment: Maybe there is one allready. You cannot create 2 files with same name

Comment: permit means allowed. If it's possible, how can create a partial class file in above folder? 2 files with different name, but been a partial class for **MyForm** class.

Comment: just call it as you like, and add it to the Project in the Project explorer. e.g. MyFormExtension.cs and write the code there, but im pretty sure the file exists allready, when using VS

Comment: press F7 in Visualstudio Form and you get to the code, alternatively righclick: "View code"